# centering items even with or without labels

Tags: html, css

I have this on my codepen in which I was using flex to align items. What I want is to align items even with or without labels.

here is my html code:

```
<div class="parent-main">
<div class="child1">
<!--<label>checkbox</label> -->
<input type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="child2">
 <label>checkbox</label>
 <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div class="child3">
 <label>checkbox</label>
 <input type="radio"/>
</div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.parent-main {
display: flex;
justify-items: center;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
width: 55vh;
height: 25vh;
margin: 5px;
padding: 15px;
gap: 2px;
}

.child1 {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
/*   position: relative;
top: 2px; */
}

.child2 {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: baseline;
}

.child3 {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: baseline;
}
```

Here is my codepen link: [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/lutherjohn/pen/gOeWXNp)

This is quite tricky on my side but I hope I can have your insights on this, been working this for 2 days now.

Comment: By "labels" you mean `label` tags?

Comment: yes, indeed by using ```label```

Comment: Without any of the labels or only the one commented out?

Comment: the problem with it is that what if I will not put some ``` label ``` to some of it and the others I will put some ``` label ``` with it, but I want them align to every ``` input type ```

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to align the `input` of type "text" with the other `div` siblings but without it having any `label` element, we use a line break in order to mimic an empty blank space without any text element in it by using either `<br>` or `&nbsp;`

**Tip:**
Avoid duplication of codes in CSS properties, see the below snippet

```css
.parent-main {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 55vh;
  height: 25vh;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  gap: 2px;
}

.parent-main>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child2,
.child3 {
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-main">
  <div class="child1">
    <!--empty space -->
    <br>
    <!-- &nbsp; can also be used -->
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <label>checkbox</label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <label>checkbox</label>
    <input type="radio" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will give it a try, I'll come come back if the problem is resolve. Thank you.